# Dynamically Removing Inputs / DOM Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I've been able to make a section of a form that dynamically adds a tier of inputs on a button click.  This new div is appended after the previous div and I am attempting to make a button that can also remove the tier if the user doesn't need it.

My problem is I cannot seem to remove the divs.  I can add but not remove.  When I look at the DOM I can see when the  addDiv button is clicked, it is indeed adding the div and all the content is within the div, so it is being appended properly.  But when I try to remove the newly appended div from it's parent element, I get the following error thrown:

```
addJob.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefinedremoveJob @ addJob.js:18onclick @ index.html:1
```

I'm unsure how to make my `removeJob()` function defined in a way that is just the reverse of how it was added.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theodore_steiner/pen/WGEmGr

```js
var i = 0;

function addJob() {

  if (i <= 1) {
    i++;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="schoolBoard_' + i + '"> '+ 
                     '<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="position_' + i + '"> '+
                     '<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="years_' + i + '">'+
                     '<input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeJob()">';

    document.getElementById("employmentHistory").appendChild(div);
  }
}

function removeJob(div) {
  document.getElementById("employmentHistory").removeChild(div.parentNode);
  i--;
};
```

```css
button {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
input[type="button"] {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
input[type="button"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input.three-lines {
  margin-left: 18px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c1cc;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page2-content">
  <div class="input-group" id="previousTeachingExperience">
    <label id="teachingExpierience">Teaching Experience *</label>

    <div id="employmentHistory">
      <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="schoolBoard_1" placeholder="School Board" onblur="this.placeholder='Email'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" />
      <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="position_1" placeholder="Position" onblur="this.placeholder='Position'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" />
      <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="years_1" />
      <input type="button" name="myButton" onclick="addJob()" value="+" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps because you don't send a parameter to removeJob?

Comment: Added a snippet using the `<>` button in the editor. Fix the error showing in the console - it is missing something: `removeJob(this)`

Comment: I have updated my ans...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You function is right just add the paramter "this" when you put the function in the onclick attribute, like this:

```
onclick="removeJob(this)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By adding the "this" does that essentially define what the parentNode is?

Comment: No it defines what the button clicked is. You then remove its parentNode

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner the define the current element

Comment: Makes sense!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, As per Below discussion passing ***`this`*** in the parameter is the best way to achieve this.

Below is the working code for this-

```js
var i = 0;
var div = null;
function addJob()
{
   
   if(i <= 1)
   {
        i++;
       div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="schoolBoard_'+i+'"> <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="position_'+i+'"> <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="years_'+i+'"><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeJob(this)">';
    
    document.getElementById("employmentHistory").appendChild(div);
   }
}

function removeJob(div)
{
    document.getElementById("employmentHistory").removeChild(div.parentNode);
    i--;
};
```

```css
button
{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input[type="button"]
{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

input[type="button"]:focus
{
   outline: none;
}

input.three-lines
{
    margin-left: 18px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c1cc;
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page2-content">
                <div class="input-group" id="previousTeachingExperience">
                    <label id="teachingExpierience">Teaching Experience *</label>
                
                    <div id="employmentHistory">
                        <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="schoolBoard_1" placeholder="School Board" onblur="this.placeholder='Email'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" />
                        <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="position_1" placeholder="Position" onblur="this.placeholder='Position'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" />
                        <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="years_1" />
                        <input type="button" name="myButton" onclick="addJob()" value="+" />
                    </div>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Post the solution here with explanation here. External links go dead

Comment: Because it is poor practice. If you need time to fix, first tell us the fix, then post the code

Comment: Passing (this) is a much better way. Your code deletes the last div created instead of the div belonging to the button

Comment: Thank you so much! By adding the "this" does that essentially define what the parentNode is?

Comment: Please note this code does not currently work. Add two rows, fill in different data, then click the middle button. It will remove the last added row

Comment: I removed the down vote but now your code is the same as the accepted answer